# Why do I get undefined result from Promise?

Tags: angular, angular-promise, angular7

I have Promise function that return data:

```
private initializePeriod(profile: Profile): Promise <any> {
    return this.educationPeriod.getCurrentStudyPeriodPromise(profile.organization.id);
}
```

Where `getCurrentStudyPeriodPromise()` get returns:

```
return this.http.post('', data).toPromise();
```

I call this promise like:

```
 return this.initializePeriod(profile)
                  .then((currentPeriod) => {
           console.log(currentPeriod);
});
```

Why I can undefined in console.log instead data from response?

Method request is:

```
public getCurrentStudyPeriodPromise(schoolId: number): Promise<any> {
 const data = { '$type': 'ReadRequest', 'query': 'getCurrentStudyPeriod', 'parameters': {'school': schoolId} }; 

return this.http.post('', data).toPromise(); }
```

I tried to use Mockup to test this:

```
private initializePeriod(profile: Profile): Promise <any> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
       this.educationPeriod.getCurrentStudyPeriodPromise(profile.organization.id).then(r => {
            resolve({'a': 1});
          }), e => {
            reject(e);
          };
        });
      }
```

So, I replaced `resolve(r);` on `resolve({'a': 1});`, and it works.

So, It means `getCurrentStudyPeriodPromise` returns incorrect promise, it returns `undefined`

Comment: Without seeing the code in `getCurrentStudyPeriodPromise()` that actually *resolves* the Promise, it's impossible to say.

Comment: Okay, code is: `public getCurrentStudyPeriodPromise(schoolId: number): Promise<any> {
    const data = {
      '$type': 'ReadRequest',
      'query': 'getCurrentStudyPeriod',
      'parameters': {'school': schoolId}
    };

    return this.http.post('', data).toPromise();
  }`

Comment: I have updated question with method

Comment: This does not look like Javascript to me...what is this?

Comment: It is TypeScript(Angular), Rxj

Comment: are you sure the promise returned by `this.http.post('', data).toPromise();` resolves to something other than `undefined`?

Comment: Do you mean I need to use `then` instanty after `.toPromise();`? And return ready result?

Comment: You know, problem is in `return this.http.post('', data).toPromise();` I verified this

Comment: what do you mean? are you saying `toPromise` returns a Promise that resolves to `undefined`?

Comment: I updated question, with mockup that I used to do tests

Comment: `.then(r => {
        resolve({'a': 1});` that looks like you're wrapping something that returns a Promise in a Promise constructor ... i.e. a common anti-pattern

Comment: How to use chain Promises then? Anyway I should return promise with data

Comment: if `this.http.post('', data).toPromise();` returns a Promise (which it looks like it would) but that promise resolves to `undefined` (which it looks like it does) then not sure what you can do about it ... what is `this.http.post` - where does this function come from?

Comment: It comes from `HttpClient` in Angular 7

Comment: Myabe it is not supported in new Angular, I mean Promises for httpClient

Comment: I checked notation of `http.post` it is really does not support Promise, how to be if I need to do actions consistently, first to do own calculations and then call method, in the end return result of both as Promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for putting this in an answer it's just a lot of code so...

but you could return an Observable and then subscribe to it

```
public getCurrentStudyPeriodPromise(schoolId: number): Observable<any> {
  const data = { '$type': 'ReadRequest', 'query': 'getCurrentStudyPeriod', 'parameters': {'school': schoolId} }; 

  return this.http.post('', data); 
}

private initializePeriod(profile: Profile): Observable<any> {
    return this.educationPeriod.getCurrentStudyPeriodPromise(profile.organization.id);
}
```

Then the method call would be

```
this.subscription = this.initializePeriod(profile)
              .subscribe((currentPeriod) => {
       console.log(currentPeriod);
});

return this.subscription
```

Only thing is you really need to make sure and unsubscribe, so later in ngOnDestroy lifecycle hook you could put

```
this.subcrption.unsubscribe();
```

I know it's not a promise so it might not be the way you want to go, but it's an option.

EDIT:

If you need to chain requests together you could do something like this, in this example I'm "creating a profile" then calling to get the profile that was just created.

```
onChainingRequests(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post('profile/create', profile).pipe(
    switchMap(createdProfileData => this.http.get(`getProfile?profileId=${createdProfileData.id}`));
  )
}
```

In this scenario when you call the first http you use the rxjs observable pipe method, then the http.post returns data it will feed that as the parameter into the switchMap method (imported from 'rxjs/operators') the switchMap method then returns the second http.get call.

The result is when you call onChainingRequests() the returned data is whatever is returned from the second http request.

Comment: I know, but I need to use Promise chain, and my second chain should be Promise that return Promise with data from method `getCurrentStudyPeriodPromise()`. I can not use Observer inside Promise like: `new Promise({//Here call  Observer method and get data})`

Comment: Did you get this solved?  Because you could change requests together in using the pipe method.